# How to rename a section with uppercase letters in an Assembly code?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm a little crazy with the code style ... I wonder if there is any way to declare statements like date and bss with uppercase letter I'm using the NASM editor?.

example:
`SECTION .bss` for `SECTION .BSS` is the same for DATA.

When I mounted the program, it looks like sections do not exist with `SECTION .TEXT` everything happens fine

Comment: https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html  7.9.2: _"Any section name other than those in the above table is treated by default like other in the above table. **Please note that section names are case sensitive.**"_

Comment: Also from the same page: _"Any code which comes before an explicit SECTION directive is directed by default into the .text section."_

Comment: You could use a preprocessor of some kind, but that just seems like a terrible idea because sections names *are* case-sensitive in the actual ELF file format (I think), if that's what you're assembling into.

Comment: does not have a right way then to do that?